# How to add an icon passed as function parameter to button in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build my first python GUI, and I tried to add an icons to buttons,
it's works when I add it directly but it give me "image doesn't exist' error when I pass the path throw a function

This is the worked code:

```
## This Works
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title=("Editor")
#Higher header
header = tk.Frame(master = window, relief = tk.RAISED, width = 900, height = 100,  bg = "red")
header.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

# Create Header Buttons
# Save
saveL = tk.Label(master=header, width = 30, height=30 )
saveL.grid(row=0, column=1)
save_icon = PhotoImage(file="icon/image_file_checked_28px.png")
save_btn = tk.Button(master=saveL,image = save_icon  ,relief=RAISED)
save_btn.pack()


# Get
openL = tk.Label(master=header, width = 30, height=30 )
openL.grid(row=0, column=2)
open_icon = PhotoImage(file="icon/image_file_checked_28px.png")
open_btn = tk.Button(master=openL,image = open_icon  ,relief=RAISED)
open_btn.pack()


#Edit

Base = tk.Frame(master = window, width = 900, height = 500,  bg = "white")
Base.pack(expand = True,fill = tk.BOTH)
window.mainloop()
```

and this when I pass it to a function:

```
## Does not Work!

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def header_button (col, fe):
    btn_label = tk.Label(master=header)
    btn_label.grid(row=0, column=col)
    btn_icon = PhotoImage(file=fe)
    btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=fe,relief=RAISED,text="h")
    btn.pack()
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title=("Editor")
#Higher header
header = tk.Frame(master = window, relief = tk.RAISED, width = 900, height = 100,  bg = "red")
header.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

# Create Header Buttons
# Save
header_button(1,"icon/image_file_add_28px.png")

# Get
header_button(2,"icon/image_file_checked_28px.png")

#Edit
header_button(3,"icon/photo_editor_28px.png" )

Base = tk.Frame(master = window, width = 900, height = 500,  bg = "white")
Base.pack(expand = True,fill = tk.BOTH)
window.mainloop()
```

This what I got from second code:

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d0aaa0c6893a> in <module>
     18 # Create Header Buttons
     19 # Save
---> 20 header_button(1,"icon/image_file_add_28px.png")
     21 
     22 # Get

<ipython-input-3-d0aaa0c6893a> in header_button(col, fe)
      7     btn_label.grid(row=0, column=col)
      8     btn_icon = PhotoImage(file=fe)
----> 9     btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=fe,relief=RAISED,text="h")
     10     btn.pack()
     11 

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2643             overrelief, state, width
   2644         """
-> 2645         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
   2646 
   2647     def flash(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2565         for k, v in classes:
   2566             del cnf[k]
-> 2567         self.tk.call(
   2568             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2569         for k, v in classes:

TclError: image "icon/image_file_add_28px.png" doesn't exist
```

I run the code in jupyter in diffrent cells and same file so it's impossible that the path has changed.

I tried to add 'r' or 'f' before the path and add to use `btn.config(image=fe)` instead set it up in `btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=fe,relief=RAISED,text="h")` but that didn't work either.
Also the text *h* didn't appear on the button.

Comment: As a rule, when something doesn't work in a Jupyter notebook, try copying the code to a file and run that file with plain Python.

Comment: `image=fe` in `btn = tk.Button(...)` should be `image=btn_icon` instead. Also you need to save a reference of the image, otherwise it will be garbage collected after function exits.

Comment: its just seems to be a typo there..

Comment: @RolandSmith I tried it in PyCharm, I got the same erorr, even after edit the typo.

Comment: How can I do that? @acw1668

Comment: @Astro It is mentioned in @Meritor answer.  However I don't know why you need `btn_label` as the parent of `btn`.  Just use `header` as the parent and also it is better design to pass `header` as an argument of `header_button` function.  Even better is using class instead of function.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried to use the label to have a control of the buttons' padding, actually it didn't work, with or without labels.

Comment: You can specify `padx` and `pady` options in `.grid(...)`.

Comment: Agree with @acw1668

Comment: That works, I'll try using class instead, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its just seems to be a typo there..
in your first example you are using `image = open_icon`

```
open_icon = PhotoImage(file="icon/image_file_checked_28px.png")
open_btn = tk.Button(master=openL, image = open_icon  ,relief=RAISED)
```

In your second example you are using `image=fe` instead of `image=btn_icon`

```
btn_icon = PhotoImage(file=fe)
btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=fe,relief=RAISED,text="h")
```

---

### Update

To prevent image disappearing form the button

```
def header_button (col, fe):
    btn_label = tk.Label(master=header)
    btn_label.grid(row=0, column=col)
    btn_icon = PhotoImage(file=fe)
    btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=btn_icon,relief=RAISED,text="h")
    btn.btn_icon = btn_icon
    btn.pack()
```

Comment: That's works, but it didn't show the icons. I try it in pyCharm it give me this error:    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "icon/image_file_add_28px.png": no such file or directory

Comment: its because of the scope of the image variable is method and it will destroy itself.. you will have to somehow keep the image available in memory.

there are a few options.. 
you can define the separate variable per image button 
or you can attach that to the respective widget

Comment: That Works! I just make an edit in image assignment `btn = tk.Button(master=btn_label,image=btn_icon,relief=RAISED,text="h")`